# Using Unity5 and C# get strings from input fields and display strings in another scene

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I created a game object that has dont destroy on load. I want this to be the holder for the input data so that I can access the strings in another scene. The problem is how to get the user input from the input text fields into my game object and back into a text field in another scene. I am thinking that I may use the built in scripts On End Edit (string) script attached to the input fields in the inspector in order to pass the input to my game object. My goal is to get strings from user input and display it all formatted nicely in another scene. I have also tagged all of my input fields and have attached a script to my game object that finds all game objects with the tag. This may be a better way to go about getting the strings.

Comment: You can use PlayerPrefs and store the data there, or create a static class with an array/struct/methods+properties if all data is dynamic, or a static and/or serialized class to save/restore the data. With all solutions, you don't need don't destroy GOs or anything (that was made for other purposes btw, large mesh things to survive -e.g. NPCs with stats to pull around with you between maps, etc)

Comment: I think I like the playerprefs option since I am not attempting to do anything fancy and I have never used it before. Could you give me an example of code in c# that uses playerprefs to store user input from an input field? And how would I get the stored data to display in a text field in another scene?

Comment: I'd use playerprefs to save data for another session. If you just want to save the data for another scene, use a static class. You don't even need "Dontdestroyonload"

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually need to save this data in a specific format for all future user sessions so I am going to look into player prefs. Is this code still usable with player prefs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use playerprefs to save data for another session. If you just want to save the data for another scene, use a static class. You don't even need "Dontdestroyonload"

Create this class in your project:

```
public static class ExampleUserData
{
    public static string MyUserData1;
    public static string MyUserData2;
    //etc..
}
```

Attach this class to a gameobject in your scene 1:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ExampleScene1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputField input1;
    InputField input2;

    void Awake()
    {
        //input1 = something...;
        //input2 = something...;
    }

    void LoadScene2()
    {
        ExampleUserData.MyUserData1 = input1.text;
        ExampleUserData.MyUserData2 = input2.text;

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
    }
}
```

This one in your second scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ExampleScene2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    InputField input1;
    InputField input2;

    void Awake()
    {
        //input1 = something...;
        //input2 = something...;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        input1.text = ExampleUserData.MyUserData1;
        input2.text = ExampleUserData.MyUserData2;
    }
}
```

Replace the code in the Awake() to find your input fields.

Comment: Gief him a static class example as well and we are good. I'll upvote if you show serialization with it - just to motivate you :)

Comment: The static class example is already there :P He has everything he needs on my answer I think. Serialization of what? The static class?

Comment: Hahh, avoided my attention! It really is there :) Serialization of the data to write/read (e.g. to file), but thinking of it, that would be too much of good :P Here, take my upvote :)